# Insert text at same time on different line but with different columns in Vim

Tags: vim

Lets say I have this line:

```
gonna give you up
gonna let you down
gonna run around and desert you
```

If I want to insert some text at the same time on different line and on the same columns, such like this:

```
Never gonna give you up
Never gonna let you down
Never gonna run around and desert you
```

I can use `Ctrl-v` and `Shift-i` to do the work. But what if I want to change the line into this?

```
gonna give you some_text up
gonna some_text let you down
some_text gonna run around and desert you
```

I want to insert some text at the same time on different line but on different columns. How can I do that?

Comment: If the operation is well-defined, it should be possible, but it's not really clear from your example what the principle should be. Do you mean start at column 3 and insert in the next column to the left on each subsequent line?

Comment: I just mean to just insert it on a different columns, any columns can be. Sorry if I can't express it really well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this feature is available in vanilla Vim.  There are plugins to Vim that appear to provide the capability though (see: https://github.com/hlissner/vim-multiedit).

Comment: Even multiple selection doesn't provide any real benefit since the number of operations is the same compared to simply pasting the same text line by line.

Comment: @r_31415 In an otherwise vanilla Vim installation that may be true.  Any mouse integration (like gVim) could reduce the number of keyboard operations (replaced by mouse cursor ops).  I leave it to the subjective preference of the user/reader of which they would prefer.

Comment: Yes, but we are not counting only "keyboard operations".

Comment: @r_31415 The point is moot anyway.  Like I said, it is a subjective preference.  Some people are faster in their workflow, or feel more comfortable achieving their task using this feature (thus why it exists in some popular editors and has been made a plugin in many others).  In the case of Vim, to the best of my knowledge, it requires a plugin.

Comment: Absolutely. This answer at least provides a solution in vim, however, that doesn't change the fact that the original task is rather pointless and if I had to bet, it comes from the desire to replicate the multi-cursor feature found in IDEs.